# EntityFramework postgresql: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have a code:

```
protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        SetConnection();
        SetChannel();

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        consumer.Received += async (_, ea) =>
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
            
            try
            {
                var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());
                var newCommentModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Comment>(content);

                await dbContext.AddMessageToDb(newCommentModel);

                _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(_queueName, false, consumer);
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

There are over 100k entries in my rabbitmq queue. After about 50-70 saves to the database, I get the error:

> ! An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
> ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 53300: **remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections**
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong|226_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__OpenCore|208_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
> at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> Exception data:
> Severity: FATAL
> SqlState: 53300

In my postgre settings max_connection = 100.
Most likely I get an error due to the fact that I do not close the connection to the database in time, is this so and how to fix it?

I try add

```
finally
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
```

**Do I need to somehow limit the operation of ExecuteAsync in the background? How can I limit the number of parallel processes to eg 100?**

Comment: What does `AddMessageToDb` do? How is your worker configured? How many messages are processed in parallel? Processing 1000 INSERTs in parallel won't run faster than 1 batch of 1000 INSERTS, or a `COPY`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos AddMessageToDb contains await DbContext.AddAsync(model); and await SaveChangesAsync();. What kind of worker configuration are we talking about? I did not find the settings for the background service in the documentation. Apparently, any possible number of processes are being processed in parallel...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you using a BackgroundService? In that case your code spawns a new DbContext and by extension connection for every message. That's not good, no matter what technology you use. You quickly end up trying to execute 100 concurrent INSERTs. The `EventingBasicConsumer` doesn't understand asynchronous event handlers so it doesn't check to see if the event handler completed. [According to the docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming-async) you need to use `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` instead, with a special setting in the connection factory

Comment: In `EventingBasicConsumer.Received`, `async (_, ea)` results in an `async void` delegate that can't be awaited. `EventingBasicConsumer`'s event raising code doesn't know anything about tasks and won't try to await anything anyway. [AsyncEventingBasicConsumer.Received](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/api/RabbitMQ.Client.Events.AsyncEventingBasicConsumer.html#RabbitMQ_Client_Events_AsyncEventingBasicConsumer_Received) on the other hand, expects a `Task` result and *will* await for it to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EventingBasicConsumer doesn't understand asynchronous event handlers so it doesn't check to see if the event handler completed. In `EventingBasicConsumer.Received` the handler `async (_, ea)` results in `an async void` delegate that can't be awaited:

```
async void OnReceived(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs)
{
    ...
    await dbContext.AddMessageToDb(newCommentModel);
    ...
}
```

`async` methods return to the caller when the first `await` is encountered. It's up to the caller to await the async operation in turn. With `async void` though, there's no task to await. The client assumes the event was processed and pops the next message in the queue.

As a result, the current code will spawn DbContexts and by extension connections, without waiting for the INSERT operations to complete, quickly exhausting the database's connection limit.

[According to the docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consuming-async) you need to use AsyncEventingBasicConsumer instead, with a special setting in the connection factory :

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
// ...
// use async-oriented consumer dispatcher. Only compatible with IAsyncBasicConsumer implementations
factory.DispatchConsumersAsync = true;

var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        // copy or deserialise the payload
        // and process the message
        // ...

        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        await Task.Yield();

    };
// this consumer tag identifies the subscription
// when it has to be cancelled
string consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

This should receive messages one by one and await for DbContext or Dapper to INSERT them before receiving another.

This will solve the immediate problem, but it's probably too slow. Instead of executing 100K inserts one by one, a better idea would be to batch them and insert eg 100 at once.

One way to do that is to use eg a [BatchBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.batchblock-1?view=net-7.0) to batch messages together and an `ActionBlock<Comment[]>` to insert these to the database. The `Received` event handler will post comments to the BatchBlock without waiting for the entire batch to complete:

```
public MyServiceConstructor(...)
{
   _batch=new BatchBlock<Comment>(100);
   _importer=new ActionBlock<Comment[]>(ImportAsync);

   _batch.LinkTo(importer,= new DataflowLinkOptions()
        {
            PropagateCompletion = true
        });
   ...
}

protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
   ...
   consumer.Received += async (ch, ea) =>
   {
       ...
       await _batch.SendAsync(comment);
    };

    ...    
}

async Task ImportAsync(Comment[] comments)
{
    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
    try
    {
        dbContext.Comments.AddRange(comments);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

When the BackgroundService needs to exit, `_batch.Complete()` should be called to tell the blocks they can complete, eg in `StopAsync`. The code should wait for `_importer` to complete with `await _importer.Completion;`

This leaves acknowledgements as an excercise to the reader. Acknowledging messages before batching risks losing messages in case of error. Acknowledging them inside `Import` risks losing acknowledgements if an entire batch is lost.

Assuming `Comment` somehow carries the tag, `Import` could ACK or NACK an entire batch  at once :

```
async Task ImportAsync(Comment[] comments)
{
    using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestContext>();
    try
    {
        dbContext.Comments.AddRange(comments);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        foreach(var c in comments)
        {
            _channel.BasicAck(c.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
    ...
        foreach(var c in comments)
        {
            _channel.BasicNack(c.DeliveryTag, false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I changed the EventingBasicConsumer to the AsyncEventingBasicConsumer, added line DispatchConsumersAsync = true to the ConnectionFactory configuration and it worked for me.

Also thanks for the tip on the BatchBlock, I'll try to implement it.